# What's the deal with Actors? (Design Patterns)

Tags: design-patterns, actor

I've seen a lot of game engines use Actors and I can't find any sites that explain why they are called actors and what they represent in the hierarchy. I encountered it latest in [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/44255/263415.aspx) forum post. It appears from his post that using actors with components defining their behavior is called the composition method. What other design patterns are there, and which do you prefer for a 2d platformer? 3d game?

Comment: This might be better for the Game Dev Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I'll move it right away.

Comment: Perhaps separate this into multiple questions. There is too much going on and it's not all related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking a bunch of different questions, here. But, as to the one in the title:

Actors receive that name because [they are those that act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_%28UML%29) on other components.